# Set vertical/horizontal image same height in carousel

Tags: 7

I'm using `Owl Carousel` to display images, but I don't know how to set horizontal pictures same height as vertical pictures without screwing up the whole carousel.

This is the page: [link](http://erlinevanhijfte.be/ouap)

I've tried to set `.owl-item` to `width:auto` but that will only cut the carousel at the end. It will stop at a certain point and won't let me see the other images.

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="owl-item" style="width: 409px;"><div class="item-0">  
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-foto-beauty">        
    <div class="field-content">
      <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://erlinevanhijfte.be/sites/default/files/IMG_5283.jpg" width="667" height="1000" alt="" title="">
    </div>  
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```